# How do I loop through guid generation a specific number of times?

Tags: powershell, loops

I put together this script from various sources to generate a guid, but now I want to loop this so it will generate and output 10 results:

```
$Guid = [guid]::NewGuid()
$Password = [string]$Guid
$Password = $Password.Replace("-", "")
Clear-Host
$Password
Clear-Variable -Name "Guid"
Clear-Variable -Name "Password"
```

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. [SO] is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask] a Good Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below will do what you need.

I am initializing the loop then using the `New-Guid` function instead of `[guid]::NewGuid()` then converting it to a string and replacing the `-` with nothing

```
for($i=1; $i -le 10; $i++){
    (New-Guid).Guid.tostring().Replace("-", "")
}
```

Please read up on for loops [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_for?view=powershell-7.1#support-for-multiple-operations) so you can change it where necessary

Comment: How does this compare performance-wise to `1..10|ForEach-Object { (New-Guid).Guid.ToString().Replace("-","") }`?

Comment: @jeff, I'd assume it's a bit slower due to using the pipeline.

Comment: @jeff for this scenario it appears that the ```for``` loop is on average 20% faster than the ```Foreach-Object```. Performance seems to vary greatly though

Answer (score 0):

```
1..4 |  % { [System.Guid]::NewGuid() }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thanks for answering. Please edit this answer to describe how it works and why it is a solution for OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to use `.Replace` to remove the hyphens from a new [`Guid` instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid?view=net-6.0), simply calling the [`Guid.ToString` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.tostring?view=net-6.0#system-guid-tostring(system-string)) with the **`N` format** will do that for you:

```
$guids = 0..9 | ForEach-Object { [guid]::NewGuid().ToString('N') }
```